# Is it possible to create a C++ library referencing only a DLL?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 on Windows 10. I am trying to create a C++ library and I need to reference an existing DLL file. The DLL file is in the project folder, but it does not show up when I right-click on the References drop-down in the project and select "Add Reference". There is also no option to browse for one.
I was reading around and it seems like I need a .lib file as well? All I have is the DLL file however.
I am also sort of a noob, so if it can be explained in layman's terms that would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: The short answer is no, you can't add a reference to a DLL like this.  The DLL _might_ be usable without an import library (`.lib`) depending on what sort of DLL it is.  What does the DLL contain?

Comment: It's an open source called Magick.NET-Q8-x64.Native.dll. It contains functions and structures for doing work on images.

Comment: This appears to be a .NET project.  You should create a new project in C# and add it to your project through the NuGet package manager.

Comment: My library needs to be created in C++. I was under the impression that C++ and C# could communicate with each other, is this not the case?

Comment: It is the case, but we generally don't do it unless we have to.  Since this is a new project and you've got a dependency on .NET anyway, you might as well do it in a .NET language.  If you're set on this for whatever reason, you can use either `COM` or `C++/CLI`.  (The former is the better option, but will require a `COM` visible interface to the lilbrary, which you'll have to write if it doesn't already provide one.)

Comment: I will try this out. Thank you